# Use filters in angular templates to display object/model property don't work

Tags: angularjs

I have this:

```
//key has the following format  "first.second.third";
//splitString is returning the part after last .

{{object.eventMap[key|splitString:'.':-1]}} doesn't work.
```

This is under a ng-repeat, so would be pretty hard to make it separately in controller.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's not how filters work.
In this case I'd suggest that you simply call a function in your current scope from withing the expression:

```
{{object.eventMap[figureOutKey(key)]}}
```

This function `figureOutKey` is defined in your controller and returns the modified key.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the filter in parenthesis like this:

```
{{object.eventMap[(key|splitString:'.':-1)]}}
```

Hope this helps.